# How can I tell when a custom name server is active?

Tags: nameserver

I recently moved my website to a VPS solution and in doing so was instructed to set up two custom nameservers with my domain registrar: ns1.mydomainname.com and ns2.mydomainname.com

I followed the instructions but I am not sure how to tell if they are actually active. I tried checking on http://www.whatsmydns.net/ and it resolves to the current IP for my active site.

My point is to make sure the nameservers are 'live' before I make the switch. What is the recommended way to confirm a custom nameserver is valid?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to wait 72 hours for see it on DNS checks sites such as that. You can check your settings internally and at your registrar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the nameservers appear in Internic's WHOIS `http://www.internic.net/whois.html`, it can take up to a few hours for DNS record changes for a domain to propagate throughout the Internet to DNS servers.

You can Google online "NSLookup" tools to verify that the nameservers resolve and are pointing to the correct IP address. Within a 24 hour period of confirming that, you should be safe to switch to the new nameservers.

Comment: Dan, Thank you for the info. This is what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Always scary stuff when you're making DNS changes to a live site...but if different online tools can see them, visitors can too.